# Cannot git push using local config username

Tags: git, github

I have two github account, one for work (username_work) and one personal (username_personal).
I have two repo - repo_work and repo_personal.

I was using repo_work till now with username_work. Now I have created repo_personal and username_personal. I want to use the username_personal with repo_personal.

I did following:

```
git clone url_to_repo_personal.
cd repo_personal
git config --local --replace-all user.name "username_personal"
git config --local --replace-all user.email "email_username_personal_account_created_from"
```

the local git config contains correct username i.e. username_personal. 
But when I do git push origin dev, it used my office username. I have also create new SSH keys using my personal email and updated in my github profile. Any solution ??

Comment: I believe that `user.name` has nothing to do with the user used in RelNotes, but is only the name used for commits. You should check your ssh config: maybe the github host is associated with the username_work key

Comment: Then how can I make git push though my new personal git account on the same system.

Comment: You should setup your keys correctly, for example as shown in this article https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-work-with-github-and-multiple-accounts--net-22574

Comment: Thanks much. That helped.

P.S. I had to delete my .git/hooks/pre-push . I am not sure what caused following error:

This repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path. If you no longer wish to use Git LFS, remove this hook by removing .git/hooks/pre-push